# How to calculate func in c#?

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
eight(minus(three())); should return 5
eight(plus(three())); should return 11
```

I only added two functions:

```
private static Func<int> Minus(
       Func<int> left,
       Func<int> right)
       => left - right;

private static Func<int> Plus(
       Func<int> left,
       Func<int> right )
       => left + right;
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Before c# is able to evaluate what `eight()` returns, it should evaluate the output for `minus()`, and before that it should know what the output for `three()` is. Currently you only provides an implementation for `minus()`, (when limiting to the first line), so you should implement a function `three()` and a function `eight()`.

Comment: Well for a start, your `Minus` and `Plus` methods (which aren't `minus` or `plus` as per the sample) accept two functions, but your sample only accepts one...

Comment: There are many ways to write these functions, not all necessarily in the spirit of the exercise. For example, start off with `int minus(int x) => -x` and `int plus(int x) => x` and then try to work out what `eight` and `three` should be.

Comment: This is all really peculiar code, it looks more like F# currying than C# code. You can write all of this without any `Func`s at all.

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code, but perhaps reading about [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1?view=net-6.0) would be helpful

Comment: @JonSkeet I just wanted to use math operations using left and right parts

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by that, but it doesn't seem to be relevant to my point anyway - you're calling a method with two parameters (both required), but only passing in one argument. That won't work.

Comment: I guess the compiler has something to say about your "problem". Can you share its messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
    double One( Func<double>? right=null)=> 1 + (right!=null ? right(): 0 );
    double Two( Func<double>? right=null)=> 2 + (right!=null ? right(): 0 );
    double Three( Func<double>? right=null)=> 3 + (right!=null ? right(): 0 );
    double Four( Func<double>? right=null)=> 4 + (right!=null ? right(): 0 );
    double Five( Func<double>? right=null)=> 5 + (right!=null ? right(): 0 );
    double Six( Func<double>? right=null)=> 6 + (right!=null ? right(): 0 );
    double Seven( Func<double>? right=null)=> 7 + (right!=null ? right(): 0 );
    
    double Eigth(Func<double>? right =null)=> 8 + (right != null ? right() : 0);
    double Nine(Func<double>? right =null)=> 9 + (right != null ? right() : 0);
    double Zero(Func<double>? right =null)=> 0 + (right != null ? right() : 0);
    
    
    Func<double> Plus(double right) => () => right;
    Func<double> Minus(double right) => () => right * -1;
    
    
    
    Console.WriteLine(Eigth(Minus(Three())).ToString()); // 5 
    Console.WriteLine(Eigth(Plus(Three())).ToString()); // 11
    
    Console.WriteLine(One(Minus(Three())).ToString()); // -2 
    
    Console.WriteLine(One(Plus(Four())).ToString()); // 5
    Console.WriteLine(One(Plus(Zero())).ToString()); // 1
    Console.WriteLine(Two(Plus(Five())).ToString()); // 7
    
    Console.WriteLine(Seven(Minus(Six())).ToString()); // 1
    Console.WriteLine(Nine(Plus(Six())).ToString()); // 15
    Console.Write(Seven(Plus(Nine(Plus(Two()))))); // 18 
    Console.WriteLine(Two(Plus(Nine(Minus(One(Plus(Seven()))))))); // 2 + ( 9 - (1 + 7) ) = 3
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Two(Plus(Nine(Minus(One(Plus(Seven())))))));`
looks so strange and I don't understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

This will work, which will keep the intermediate results in a variable `x`, and will default to add the value. The output of `eight(three())` will also be 11.

```cs
int x;

static int Minus(int x) {
    x=-x;
    return x;
}
static int Plus(int x) {
    return x;
}

static int three(int x=0) {
    x=x+3;
    return x;
}

static int eight(int x=0) {
    x=x+8;
    return x;
}

int y = eight(Minus(three()));
System.Console.WriteLine( y  );

y = eight(Plus(three()));
System.Console.WriteLine( y  );
```

output:

```
5
11
```

Comment: An interesting solution demonstrating how a seemingly unsuspicious group cannot be expanded to a ring (with the usual definition of multiplication).